# From where does Model get data in MVVM?

Tags: design-patterns, mvvm, silverlight-4.0

I am currently studying MVVM pattern. I am clear with the concept that `Model` contains classes, `View` is just the visual representation of data and `ViewModel` is the layer that connects `Model` and `View` and carry out all manipulations.

But i m still not clear with the fact that from where does `Model` get data? Since it contains only properties. So even if we use WCF to fill in data, still the question remains:

Is any intermediate class required to fill in data in `Model` or this work is also carried out via `ViewModel`?

`Model` gives data to `ViewModel`, which in turn gives formatted data to `View` and `View` just represents the data. But from where does `Model` get the data?

Answer (score 0):

Think about the Model in a more abstract way. The 'Model' is generally one, or more, classes that allow you to get/work with the data you need to populate the ViewModel. It could be a repository, a class hierarchy, etc.

For example:

I have a ViewModel that shows a customer's details and their orders. For the sake of the example, I am not using a domain model, just some DAOs. To populate the ViewModel I need customer data and order data. This data is accessed by a Customer DAO and an Order DAO. I get customer by id and then the customer's orders by id. I add all this data to the ViewModel for display. In this example, my 'Model' is the two DAOs, or a wrapper around the DAOs.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)'s another example where repositories are used instead of DAOs.

Comment: So does that mean that we need an intermediate class that will populate data into Model?